# Is "be on about (something)" used in American English?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

*Be on about (something)*

> To speak about something tediously and at great length. (**Primarily heard in UK.**)
>
> > - He just kept rambling about literary metaphors and imagery. I didn't know what he was on about!
> > - She's always on about some new show she has started watching.

Source: The Free Dictionary https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+about.

So will this be used in AmE?

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster says the same thing about [**on about**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20about):

> British, informal + disapproving
>   : talking about
>   // I haven't a clue what you're *on about*!
>   // She is *always on about* the importance of exercise.

But is it used in US English *at all*?

---

Per Google Books Ngram Viewer, *always on about* had a frequency of 0.0000013079% in the [UK corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always%20on%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20on%20about%3B%2Cc0) in 2000:

[image: always on about—UK]

Meanwhile, *always on about* had a frequency of 0.0000004296 in the [US corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always%20on%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20on%20about%3B%2Cc0) in 2000:

[image: always on about—US]

---

This shows the frequency of that phrase specifically in the printed material that Google tracks. So, it is at best only a rough guide to usage—and it doesn't account for spoken English or informal writing that wouldn't make its way into book form.

But, *based purely on that*, it suggests that out of its combined UK and US English usage, 75% of its use comes from the UK, while 25% comes from the US.

In other words, it's used three times more often in the UK than it is in the US. However, it *is* used in the US to some degree.

---

Barring some other form of objective data I can't think of, any other answer can only be speculation or personal opinion.

Comment: Do you use it? If not, do you have any more common alternatives?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish The most common alternative is simply *What are you* ***talking*** *about?*